# Передача ссылки с мобильного браузера в моё приложение

Tags: android, android-intent, share, link

Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии в браузере опции поделиться (share) в открывающемся списке сриде возможных приложений было и моё. При выборе своего приложения, я хочу, чтобы оно получало ссылку данного сайта. Я не знаю как это реализовать и какие интент фильтры для этого нужны. Пожалуйста, подскажите как это сделать, или нужные для этого технологии.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала добавьте в свой manifest intent-filter для той Activity, где вы будете принимать Intent.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MyTheme" >

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Ваше приложение должно теперь быть в списке "поделиться".

Далее в  Activity принимаем Intent:

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
Log.d("MyActivity", "onCreate: " + url);
```